# Email field turns to radio button

Tags: jquery, input, radio-button, codepen

I have this codepen: https://codepen.io/stdobrescu/pen/xxbMbLK
The last field, which is an text input, turns to a radio button when any other radio input is clicked. I can't find out what triggers that.
This is the field:

```
 <div class="input-block">
        <label>Your email</label>
        <div class="input-control">
          <input type="email" name="firstname" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
    var question = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var totalScore = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
      if ((question[i].type = "radio")) {
        if (question[i].checked) totalScore += parseInt(question[i].value, 10);

        console.log(totalScore);
        displayLevel(totalScore);
        $("#score").html(totalScore);
      }
    }});
```

Comment: Include the logic in your codepen in your question.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].  To help your question, please include a [mcve] with all relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: `if ((question[i].type = "radio")) {` should be `if ((question[i].type == "radio")) {` - by using `=` you're converting the input into a radio instead of using `==` to check if it's a radio.

Comment: @Taplar Thanks, will do from now on ;)

Comment: @freedomn-n that seems to do the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> try by getElementsByClassName instead of getElementsByTagName

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
    var question = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");
    var totalScore = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
      if ((question[i].type = "radio")) {
        if (question[i].checked) totalScore += parseInt(question[i].value, 10);

        console.log(totalScore);
        displayLevel(totalScore);
        $("#score").html(totalScore);
      }
    }});
```